# Creating a script on notepad and test it on cmd to attach or detach a database in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have no programming experience, I need an example how to attach or detach a database 
so far I have come to this

```
cd /d "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin"
mysql -uroot -p1234 -e "show databases;" 
Pause
```

How do I make this script to attach or detach a database. I need 2 scripts, and there are no examples anywhere, usually I know the command but it is for SQL not MYSQL and I get syntax error.

Could someone write down an example for this so I can use it?

after your advise 
...............................
I am not sure what kind of table engine is ... I am using virtual machine that is running on windows server 2012 r2, and im writing the code on the notepad that is on the operating system on that virtual machine ... how can i define if im using MyISAM or InnoDB?

okey i am on 
mysql> and i type 
mysql>mysql dump -uroot -p1234 sakila>remy.sql  and it goes to the next row and shows ->

Answer (score 0):

What kind of table engine do you use, MyISAM or InnoDB?

With MyISAM its as simple as just copying all the .frm, .MYI, and .MYD files from the database directory. In your case, it's in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\{$DATABASE_NAME}`

With InnoDB it's not so simple, and probably best to use mysqldump.

**Backup:**

```
mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql
```

**Restore:**

```
mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql
```